# Use url parameter in application ui router startup?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So, what I'm stuck on is that I'm trying to use a parameter in startups.   But I'm stuck in an application lifecycle startup issue.

http://someapp/configtoken/action

http://someapp/index.html
and the controller is essentially indexController.

In indexController, I'd like to take the configToken and go do some kind of web service hit to determine what I should or should show.

But, when I just dumpe configToken out to the console, nothing is defined.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: share your code in jsfiddle

Comment: I'd like too, but I'm still learning how to do that.